# Using route links with tabbed nav pills in Bootstrap Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, routes

The following code works for the tabbing but the links show no effect. When I remove `data-toogle` or set `data-toggle="link"` the links are fine but the tabbing is gone. So how to get tabs with route links? Thanks.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-light bg-white">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary nav-pills-icons justify-content-center" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" style="padding -right:0.9em;">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="{{ route('user.index') }}" role="tablist">User </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="{{ route('page.charts') }}" role="tablist" margin="30px">Charts </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: it is possible that you are not referencing jQuery, please check to make sure jQuery is the first on the list

Comment: jQuery is supposed to be referenced by the laravel framework. can you give an example where you think it should be referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<a class="nav-link {{ Route::is('user.index') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="link" href="{{ route('user.index') }}" role="tablist">User </a>
```

```php
<a class="nav-link {{ request()->is('page.charts') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="link" href="{{ route('page.charts') }}" role="tablist" margin="30px">Charts </a>
```

Comment: okay, this seems to be a workaround and the switching works but there is another problem now: there is no button active by default when the user enters the page.

Comment: @Rome "when the user enters the page" what's the route for this page? is it `user.index`?

Comment: @Rome is the tab url the same as "when the user enters the page"?

Comment: yes, the user logs in and sees the charts, so it's `page.charts`

Comment: @Rome I think it's because it's your named routes problem, change `Route::is('page.charts')` to `Route::is('/charts')` the actual url.

Comment: if i change to `Route::is('/charts')` the button highlighting does not work, with `Route::is('page.charts')` it does

Comment: @Rome I mean change to your actual real URL, I do not know what's your URL,

Comment: i just did and it's the same: the link works but the button does not highlight, there's also no button highlighted when user enters the website.

Comment: hey, i found it, the problem is in my routing: after login the user is routed to 'home' and 'home' redirects to 'charts'. so the chart button cannot be highlighted by start, because it comes initially from 'home', not from 'page.charts'. please change back your solution to `request()->is('page.charts')`, because it works!